# What is the number of filter when using CNN for sentence classification

Tags: classification, neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, natural-language

I am new to machine learning and NLP.

During reading [convolutional neural networks for sentence classification](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D14-1181) I'm having trouble understanding it.

In the paper it says that a feature map **c** has [image] features. where n is the total length and h is the number features in it. But the figure given with it makes me confused. 
[image]

For the Red filter, I thought that n would be 9 and h would be  2, making a featuremap of 8 features. but the figure shows a filtermap of 7 features. For the Yellow filter I thought 9-3+1=7 features should be right but the picture indicates 6 features. What am I missing?

This is my first time postiing a question. So, if anythings inappropriate please tell me.

Comment: I think you're right, there should be 8 and 7 channels in the output instead of 7 and 6. It might be their mistake, in the diagram.